# Finding the index # of a layer after locating it by name

Tags: javascript, object, layer, indexof, adobe-illustrator

I understand layer names are only accessible as objects. But is there a way to use that object name to find the index position in an array as well? In other words, I have multiple layers in a file. i want to find a particular layer, lock and change the visibility of all the layers above it and unlock and change the visibility of all the layers below it. I will always be looking for the same layer but the total layer count changes from job to job. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through all the layers and check if each one matches your name.. if it does save the index (current count of loop).

```
// get index (from top layer down) of named layer... expects only one layer  with this name
// name of layer you are looking for
var targetLayerName = 'name'  

var targetDocument = app.activeDocument;
var layerCount = targetDocument.layers.length;
var namedLayerIndex = 0;
// loop through layers and find the named layer
for ( i = 0; i < layerCount; i++ ) {
    if (targetDocument.layers[i].name == targetLayerName) {
        namedLayerIndex = i;
    }
}
```